# In meta, can I use custom name-content pairs?

Tags: html

For example, can I use

```
<meta name="partofseries" content="yes">
<meta name="whichpart" content="1">
```

so that when using JS to dynamically render a table of contents, I can get the info that this is part 1 of a series from the HTML document?

Comment: You *can*. I'm not sure why you would, when you can just as easily write JavaScript that represents the same data. E.g. `<script>const metadata = { series: true, part: 1 };</script>`

Comment: Note that there are rules around some names. Check the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element).